# Can we also use conjugate of Voltage (V*) for measurement of Complex Power?

Tags: ac, power-measurement

Why is S = V I* is used a lot? I have never heard a mention of S = V* I. (It does the same job as I*). We get the phase differences in both the cases due to conjugation. So I'm assuming it is right to do V*, correct me if I'm missing any point here.
Also If I'm using V* for Complex Power calculation, will it give the same information regarding Lead/Lag Load or the Reactive power?

Comment: Yes, you are correct that power works either way. Are you asking why? Or just if you are right? As far as lead/lag goes the sign is opposite. Can you perform the multiplication to see why? (Multiplication in the complex domain is just rotation and scaling operations, combined.)

Comment: @jonk Yes, I was wondering whether I was right. I thought there might be some cases where taking Voltage Conjugate would fail. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I guess it's convention, like the electron flow direction and the conventional current direction. Just be consistent.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio When using the words "lead" and "lag", it's been decided that this means "current leads" or "current lags" with the implication being that this is *with respect to voltage*. So, I suppose in that way it is a matter of convention.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically it's true (with a sign difference, as jonk mentions in the comments), but practically, V is used as the reference, while I will lead or lag in relation to V. Therefore φ is attached to I, rather than V, so even if the voltage is V∠θ and the current I∠γ, θ is considered the reference, and thus the result is a function of the difference of angles, φ=θ-γ. If I was the reference, then IV* would be used.